# how to download IE for mac and to install

Tags: macos, internet-explorer

i want to use internet explorer on my mac, is there any way to install.

i need it as there are some websites which can open only in internet explorer, its a loss for me that i cant open websites on this safari

kindly help me if any one knows or using IE.

do you have any idea about virtualbox. is this help to download IE for mac

http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Run-Internet-Explorer-on-Mac-OS-X-391323.shtml

above link shows how todownload virtualbox and to install it

thanks

Comment: Have you tried searching Google?

Comment: Never seen a website that doesn't open in Safari or Firefox for Mac.

Comment: Since this is a user question and not a programmer question, it really belongs on either Ask Different or Super User (both Stack Exchange sites).  In answer to the question, IE does not exist for the Mac any longer, so in order to run IE on your Mac, you'll need to run an emulator, such as VMWare Fusion, Parallels, or VirtualBox.  In any of these cases, you will need a Windows license to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the [ievms project](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms) that is referred to in the softpedia link you provided is pretty quick and painless to setup on OSX. Once you have installed VirtualBox it will download and install the image for you automatically.

Note that it seems like you only need one IE version (and not all of them) so make sure you specify a version to download in the curl command, for example to install Internet Explorer 8:

curl -s https://raw.github.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh | env IEVMS_VERSIONS="8" bash

Just run this command in your Terminal and it will do the rest.

Note: I've put version 8 as an example because it would be quicker to download than newer versions and is probably enough for your usage